# How to refresh 'Programs and Features' control panel applet after Inno Setup uninstall?

Tags: windows, inno-setup

I have a fairly complex Inno Setup installer that installs two applications that appear in the windows 'programs and features' control panel display.

My problem is that if the 'programs and features' window is open when you run the uninstaller my applications remain displayed even though they have actually been uninstalled.  Refreshing the 'program and features' window with F5 removes my applications from the display.

What I need to do is have my uninstaller issue a refresh command to the 'program and features' window once my uninstall has completed so my applications are no longer listed. . How do I do this?

I have this problem in XP, Vista, and Windows 7. Lots of installers do refresh the control panel after they uninstall, it can't be that hard.

Comment: No other setups do this.
You'll also find that Programs and Features tell you if the uninstaller cna no longer be found so wont cause any problems.

Comment: Installshield installers do refresh the windows program list, and my customer wants me to do the same thing.

Comment: I guess this problem was related to some old version of InnoSetup, doesn't it ? With the recent version of InnoSetup installer when you uninstall the application, the Programs and Features control panel applet is properly refreshed.